How can I recurse all folders and replace a multi line string with a single line replacement using Powershell?
I used sed to accomplish this but it changed all the line endings in my files and I think it would be good for me to learn how the same thing can be accomplished in Powershell, anyway.
I have a folder with many sub-folders of c/c++ code.  I need to recurse through each folder and replace a multi-line header with a single-line header, in all files ending in .h, .c, .hpp, or .cpp.
The current header looks like:
/************************************************************************************ ///_|
File: $Id: //perforcedepot/path/file.ext#1 $

LEGAL NOTICE: COPYRIGHT Company Inc., All Rights Reserved 
*************************************************************************************/ //|_/

The new header is:
// Copyright company name - url

How can this be done with Powershell?

what have you tried that doesn't work?

Show us the code you are trying to make work and describe what happens.

I've added an answer of my own and will update it with what I sort out.

Should be straight forward for a literal string replace.  I would backup the files just in case.
$beforestring = '/************************************************************************************ ///_|
File: $Id: //perforcedepot/path/file.ext#1 $

LEGAL NOTICE: COPYRIGHT Company Inc., All Rights Reserved 
*************************************************************************************/ //|_/'

$afterstring = '// Copyright company name - url'

$files | % { 
  (get-content -raw $_).replace($beforestring, $afterstring) | set-content $_-2
}


Thanks for the help.  A couple of questions.  What does "$files | %" do?   Also, the $beforestring needs a pattern match because the path that follows "File: $ID: " is just an example.  Every file has a different path.

ok I found an explanation.  The % symbol in that context does a foreach-object on the bracketed commands.

I didn't get from the question that the string changes.  You'll have to use -replace and a regex pattern then, and escape all the non-regex characters.

After some experimentation I realized the requirements were more complicated than I thought at the beginning, so I gave up on using Powershell and wrote a C++ program instead.  But here are the notes I had taken in case it helps someone else...
Getting a list of files
I tried this:
get-childitem -recurse -filter *.?pp -name

That seems to work, except I also got .ipp files, of course. I only want .h, .c, .hpp, and .cpp files.
So I tried this:
Get-Childitem -Path . -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -Like "*.h" -or $_.Name -Like "*.c" -or $_.Name -Like "*.hpp" -or $_.Name -Like "*.cpp" }

Which gives me the files I'm looking for, though not in the format I was expecting.
It seems that I can use -Match with regular expressions:
Get-Childitem -Path . -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '\.(c|h)pp$|\.(c|h)$' }

These last two tries aren't showing me a list of files as paths.  It seems like Powershell works in objects, not just text, which is not like bash, but seems powerful.
